Covariant derivation of a logarithmic field
Let $x(t)$ denote a curve on a smooth manifold and $x_0$ denote a fixed point on the same manifold. The map $x\mapsto \log_xx_0$ defines locally a vector field along the curve. One may therefore think of computing the covariant derivative $\nabla_{\dot x}\log_xx_0$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, such derivative would simply be $-\dot x$. Is there any geometric setting in which the same is true on a curved manifold ?
A partial answer to this question, in terms of differentials of the exponential map, reads:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\dot{x}}\lambda=-((\mathrm{d}_v\exp)^{-1}\circ(\mathrm{d}_x\exp))_{x,\lambda}(\dot{x}),
\end{equation}
where $\lambda:=\log_{x}x_0$, while $\mathrm{d}_x\exp$ and $\mathrm{d}_v\exp$ denote the partial pushforward maps of the exponential map $\exp_x(v)$. Details
may be found on pages 74-75 of the paper "Manifold Calculus in System Theory and Control—Second Order Structures and Systems"
( https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/14/6/1144 ). This, however, does not clarify under which circumstance $\nabla_{\dot{x}}\lambda = -\dot x$.
